# Distribution of two Poisson: $\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha}F_2(\alpha-t,\mu_2)P_1(t,\mu_1)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with Poisson distribution. Also, let $F_2(y,\mu_2)$ be the Poisson CDF of $Y$ with mean $\mu_2$ and $P_1(x,\mu_1)$ be the Poisson PMF of $X$ with mean $\mu_1$. Then, what would be the distribution of $h$ which is defined as follows. Can we say $h$ has a Poisson distribution or not? If so, what's its mean?

$h=\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha}F_2(\alpha-t,\mu_2)P_1(t,\mu_1)$

Comment: $h$ is not a random variable, but $h$ can be interpreted as a probability, as $\displaystyle h = \sum_{t = \alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha} \Pr\{Y \leq \alpha - t\}\Pr\{X = t\} = \Pr\{X + Y \leq \alpha, \alpha - \beta + 1 \leq X \leq \alpha\}$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please tell me how you have found the last result in more details. I understood the first part, but I can not understand why the right-hand side of the equality sign is equal to the left-hand side. Of course, $X$ and $Y$ are independent from each other. Regards